# Location Updates

Tags: android, locationmanager

Iam developing an app that do some field signal strengths calculations every second by using Handler and during the Handler period it records the coordinates and record the results & coordinates. It works fine except when real testing and when I increase the speed of the vehicle the recorded coordinates not every second while some times every 2-3-4 seconds which is not accepted by me.
The Code below:

---

```
final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,     0, this);

publicvoid method_01(LocationManager locationManager){

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
Location locationDataRate =     locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double latitude = locationDataRate.getLatitude();
double longitude = locationDataRate.getLongitude();
x=y+1;
Save to file (latitude,longitude,x);
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
}, 1000);

}
```

---

I have tried also to change the time and min. distance to (1000,0)

Comment: You need subscribe to location changes 
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1f, yourListener);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to receive an update every 1 second, you should not request more frequent updates. Therefore:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
```

Anyway, the best practice for handling location updates is not persistently looping `getLastKnownLocation` but implementing the callback of location updates. There is a bundle of examples [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location).

To your question, in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) they state that interval between updates in never guaranteed:

> The location update interval can be controlled using the minTime
>   parameter. The elapsed time between location updates will never be
>   less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location
>   Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other
>   applications.